# Query Custom Post Type and Output to timeline

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a wordpress query that outputs posts that contain the following info: - year - link to a pdf-file - title - post image

so its essentially an archive for yearly reports dating back to the 1860's until today. For the early days there arn't pdf-files/posts for every year. in the newer days in some years there are multiple files per year.

i would need the query to output an UL with the following configuration:

```
<ul>
<li class="decimal-year pdf-present"><a href="#">1860</a><div>Image, Title, PDF Link in Post</div></li>
<li class="normal-year pdf-present"><a href="">1861</a><div>Image, Title, PDF Link in Post</div></li>
<li class="normal-year no-pdf"><a href="#">1862</li>
</ul>
```

so the class should contain info if its "decimal" year like 1860, 1870, 1880, etc. or a year inbetween like 1861, 1862, 1863, etc. Then there needs to be a class noting if theres a corresponding yearly post or not. (the links will be displayed on a visual timeline) so even if there is no yearly output, there still needs to be a li element. if there are multiple files in a year there should be another ul in the div containing the data.

thats quite a query i know!

heres the query so far:

```
// set the query
        $query = array (

        'post_type' => 'jahresberichtpdf',
        'orderby' => 'jahresberichtjahr'
        );
        // loops
        $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
        if ($queryObject->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($queryObject->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $queryObject->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
        Title:<?php the_title(); ?>
        Thumbnail:<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> 

        <strong>PDF:</strong> <?php print_custom_field('jahresberichtfile:to_link'); ?>
        <strong>Year:</strong> <?php print_custom_field('jahresberichtjahr'); ?>

        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

has anybody done a query like this or would be up for the challenge? if someone is willing to put some effort in, i would show my appreciation in form of a paypal donation!

thanks, mark

Comment: It doesn't look like much of a query at all to me. It looks like you just need to Loop over the results and conditionally add the markup. What am I missing?

Comment: it might be me missing something :-) so how would i fill the "empty" years with li elements and add classes depending on years?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this to be the primary question:

> How would i fill the "empty" years with li elements and add classes
>   depending on years?

You don't really have a "query" problem, just a PHP/markup one. You need to track you years independently of your query. Below is proof-of-concept code for doing that. I did not try to make it output the precise markup you require. Be aware that the Loop is very sensitive to post order and that you need `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` or post dates will be out of order and the loop will not work correctly. It will stop at the year of the last post, not necessarily at "this year".

```
$year = 2000;
$qry = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
  )
);

if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  while ($qry->have_posts()) {
    echo $year;
    if (date('Y',strtotime($qry->post->post_date)) == $year) {
      the_title();
      $qry->the_post();
    } else {
      echo 'no posts';
      $year++;
    }
    echo '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: would this do a query to the database for every year?

Comment: It does not do an individual query per year. That would be a huge load on the server. It pulls all of your posts for that post type and prints them out by year, including "empty" years. Did you try it?