# Show all 12 months regardless they have posts

Tags: archives, wpdb, date

I need to show all months for a year for an archives page. All 12 months must be shown regardless of whether or not there are posts published for a month. Like this:

Year: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

Of course, months with published posts are links. Months with no published posts are simply the word

This is my code:

```
<ul>

<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $limit = 0;
    $year_prev = null;
    $months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month , YEAR( post_date ) AS year, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY month , year ORDER BY post_date DESC");
    foreach($months as $month) : $year_current = $month->year;
    if ($year_current != $year_prev){ if ($year_prev != null){ ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <li> <a class="year" href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/">> <?php echo $month->year; ?></a>

    <?php } ?>

    <a class="month" href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?>"><?php echo date_i18n("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></a>

    <?php $year_prev = $year_current; if(++$limit >= 10) { break; } endforeach; ?></li>
</ul>
```

I achieved what I pretend to do except for showing all the 12 months.

Comment: This is the same kind of problem as [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100789/21376) though that one deals with years and not months. Take a look. See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for pointing that answer but I actually don't know what to do with it or how to add an array. I'm not that skilled at PHP. My solution it's a mash-up of other solutions I found elsewhere. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is correct:

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 0;
$qry = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'year' => $year,
  )
);

while ($month < 12) {
  $month++;
  echo date('M',strtotime('2000-'.str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'-01 00:00:01')).'<br>';
  if ($qry->have_posts()) {
    while ($qry->have_posts()) {
      if (date('n',strtotime($qry->post->post_date)) == $month) {   
        echo " -- ";
        the_title();
        echo '<br />';
        $qry->the_post();
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Of course, you will need to set your `$year` to the year you actually want.

That should Loop through all twelve months, `echo`ing each one, checking for posts that match in the `$qry` results.

To print only the month names and links to months having posts.

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 0;
$qry = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'year' => $year,
  )
);

$months = array();
if (!empty($qry->posts)) {
  foreach ($qry->posts as $p) { 
    $months[date('n',strtotime($p->post_date))] = $p->post_date;
  }
}

while ($month < 12) {
  $month++;
  $monthname = date('M',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  echo '<li>';
    if (isset($months[$month])) {
      echo '<a class="year" href="'.get_month_link($year,$month).'" />'.$monthname.'</a>'.'<br>';
    } else {
      echo $monthname.'<br>';
    }
  echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However this prints twelve months and the post titles for each month. Like this: Jan --Post Title Feb Mar Apr --Another Post title --Another Post Title May Jun.. an so on. What I pretend is to print exactly this: 2013: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ...and if a month has posts simply the output for the month is a link to filter the posts of that month for example if May has posts the word "May" is a link to http://myblog/2013/05

Comment: @Juanma : See the edit.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I just need to asjust the output to fit the design but I'm worried about one thing... It's necessary to indicate the year? Whats would happen in 2014? What I need to happen is this:

2015: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2013: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

Comment: You can get the year dynamically with `$year = date('Y');` if that is what you want.

Comment: Great! Thank you for taking care for this problem! It works great! I tested and adjusted to my own needs and result is perfect except for one thing: it's printing only 2013 and I need to output all years and all 12 months for every years. By outputing all years I mean to show all years with posts. For example, if posts are found for 2013, 2012 and 2010 the it will print 3 rows one for each year and each row will show the 12 months.